Searching for a fable, short story, mythology for that illustrates selling shovels in a gold rush
When everyone was busy digging for gold, levi strauss sold jeans and a few others sold shovels and pick axes and became rich.
When everyone is busy building AI/ML models spending millions on experiments - in a winner take all silicon valley games - NVIDIA sold the chips (shovels) for the AI Gold Rush and is clearly the winner.
When everyone else is busy fighting, the cunning fox steals the prize and slips away with it.
Can you give a great story, a small aesop fable or arabian nights story or any other story that captures this phenomenon.

As it stands, I'm afraid this question is a poor fit for this site which looks at questions that have specific answers, not general recommendations. Unless you can focus it somehow, it will need to be closed.

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but it seems to be a recommendation request rather than an identification request. If you're actually asking us to identify a specific story that you know you've read, then please let us know and this can be reopened. But asking for general recommendations of any story fitting a particular type is, unfortunately, a type of question that's too open-ended to fit well on Stack Exchange.

Hi @Randal'Thor - I asked the question in other stack exchange and they have asked me to put it on literature - if the literature channel can't help me with connecting ideas or analogies with stories, then which other channel can?

None. That isn't what stack exchange is for. You could maybe try /r/literature on reddit?
